# IOS Mobile Safari background image position with CSS

Tags: android, css, ios, mobile, mobile-safari

This seems like a strange issue and I hope that I just overlooked something but I have a link with a background image that is positioned just to the left of it. The style below works fine in a desktop browser and on an Android browsers, but it doesn't seem to effect the position in mobile safari.

```
.load-more-link.ajax-spinner {
background: url(images/ajax-loader-dark.gif) no-repeat 20%;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 200px;
}
```

Am I overlooking something or has anyone run into similar issues? How can I position this background image in mobile safari?

Comment: Try declaring both X and Y of background position. Currently you declared only 20% (X). Put `20% 0` to be X20% Y0 and test again.

Answer (score 0):

You should complete the background styling shortcut with both the X and Y coordinate to resolve any ambiguity:

```
background: url(images/ajax-loader-dark.gif) no-repeat 20% 0%;
```

Or you could write out the position property separately:

```
background-image: url(images/ajaxloader-dark.gif);
background-position: 20% 0%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

*EDIT*

And of course, you could try fiddling those percentages. I don't know what your markup looks like, but there could be the chance the image is being obscured if it is behind something else.